# Data Visualiztion Using Java Sockets and Flask Python and Cytoscape.js dagre

Tags: javascript, java, flask, frontend, cytoscape.js

i am trying to visualize DAG graph data through java Sockets (Server-Client) i used Flask to create a web Application . The Client Should is sending the DAG graph data to the server and the server send these data to flask and flask it gonna visualize them using Cytoscape.js. it seems that everythings is running well the server the client the flask and everything it printed to console , but no graph is beeing displayed  i mean it shows no DAG graph on the page when i run the server then the Flask and then the client , also on web Console no error is given , and still not showing and displaying the graph , why is that ? and how i can lets the graph to be displayed ?

```
server : import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
    private String message;

    public void run() {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345)) { // The Server class sets up a server socket on port
                                                                    // 12345 using ServerSocket.
            System.out.println("Server is running and waiting for client to connect...");
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // waits for a client to connect
                System.out.println("Client is connected");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); // reader to
                                                                                                        // read incoming
                                                                                                        // messages from
                                                                                                        // Cleint

                message = in.readLine(); // read the message from client and store it in the message variable.

                System.out.println("Received message from client: " + message);

                // Send the message to the Flask app using a GET request. It opens a connection
                // to the URL, sends the request, and disconnects.
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:5000/send_message?message=" + message);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.getResponseCode();
                con.disconnect();

                // Send the message back to the client as a response
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println(message);

                socket.close(); // close the socket
                System.out.println("Server is running and waiting for client to next message...");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    // New method to return the message
    public String getMessageResponse() {
        return "Message from client: " + message;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.run();
    }
}
2- Client : 
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345)) {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println("node:1,node:2,relation:1->2");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
3-app.py : import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import urllib.parse

app = Flask(__name__)

nodes = {}
edges = []


@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("nodes:", nodes)
    print("edges:", edges)
    return render_template(
        "index.html", nodes=json.dumps(nodes), edges=json.dumps(edges)
    )


@app.route("/receive_message")
def receive_message():
    message = request.args.get("message")
    print("Received message:", message)
    return message


@app.route("/send_message")
def send_message():
    global nodes, edges

    message = urllib.parse.unquote(request.args.get("message"))
    message_type, message_data = message.split(":", 1)

    if message_type == "node":
        node_id = message_data
        if node_id not in nodes:
            nodes[node_id] = {"id": node_id, "label": node_id}
    elif message_type == "relation":
        source_id, target_id = message_data.split("->")
        if source_id not in nodes:
            nodes[source_id] = {"id": source_id, "label": source_id}
        if target_id not in nodes:
            nodes[target_id] = {"id": target_id, "label": target_id}
        edges.append(
            {
                "id": f"{source_id}-{target_id}",
                "source": source_id,
                "target": target_id,
            }
        )

    return "Message received and processed successfully."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
4-index.html : <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>DAG Graph Visualization</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre/dist/dagre.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-dagre/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>

    <style>
        #cy {
            height: 600px;
            width: 800px;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>

    <script>
        // Retrieve the nodes and edges data passed from the Flask app
        var nodes = JSON.parse('{{ nodes | safe }}');
        var edges = JSON.parse('{{ edges | safe }}');

        // Create a new Cytoscape instance
        var cy = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),
            elements: {
                nodes: nodes,
                edges: edges
            },
            layout: {
                name: 'dagre'
            },
            style: [
                // Define your graph styling here
                {
                    selector: 'node',
                    style: {
                        'background-color': 'blue',
                        'label': 'data(label)'
                    }
                },
                {
                    selector: 'edge',
                    style: {
                        'width': 2,
                        'line-color': 'black'
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        console.log('nodes:', nodes);
        console.log('edges:', edges);

        // Use the dagre layout
        cy.layout({
            name: 'dagre'
        }).run();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```